# Jenkins: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing issue in jenkins job(jenkins running docker) Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

I have checked java version in docker it is openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20

we can solve this in Android Studio but how can we solve while running gradle build in jenkins.

Below is the error I am getting

Build file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/CICDDemo_master/app/build.gradle' line: 2

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkins project choose the "configure" tab on the left side, then scroll down to "Properties Content" and write there:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12

GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:\